# PHP form data not collecting

Tags: php, forms

I'm creating a simple form in bootstrap. I'm not that familiar with php, but I came up with the below based on what I can find online. When a user clicks on my submit button, an email is sent, all the form fields are indicated in the email I receive, but the data is not collected. What am I doing incorrect? PHP below and form can be viewed at: http://esdclient.com/formb/masterform.html

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "ken@elschwartzodesign.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$Name    = check_input($_POST['Name']);
$Last  = check_input($_POST['Last']);
$City   = check_input($_POST['City']);
$State = check_input($_POST['State']);
$Zip = check_input($_POST['Zip']);



/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $Name
Last: $Last
City: $City
State: $State
Zip: $Zip
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.htm');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin, do I literally add dots before and after

Answer (score 0):

enctype is wrong, try enctype="multipart/form-data"